# Which country had the largest indigenous itinerant population?

Tags: anthropology

Which country has or had the largest numbers (in absolute and/or relative terms) of indigenous itinerants in any period of history? For this question, I consider itinerants to mean a group for which travel is a significant part of their lifestyle, and travels individually or as a group, through a broader settled society.

This does not include nomadic groups like the Mongols, because they did not travel through a settled society, or refugees, migrants, etc because travel was for resettlement, it was not a lifestyle. For the purposes of this discussion, I would also like to exclude the Romani (unless considering them in the country of their origin, northern India) since they are mostly concentrated in countries to which they are not (in one sense) indigenous. I would also exclude tourists because only a small proportion would fit my definition.

Comment: Dustbowl migrations in the 30's?  I assume we're also excluding the Trail of Tears and other examples of ethnic cleansing.   I had to read several times to understand why you are excluding nomadic people, and I'm still not sure I get it.  Very complicated question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Indeed. After the Monglolian expansion by Genghis Khan, their descendants became settlers around Middle Asia before Russia invaded them.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, I'm interested in itinerants who travel through urbanised/settled areas, effectively living on the fringes of society, which is why I don't want to include pastoral nomads (I should have been clearer), marauding invaders, etc. There does not seem to be a word for such a group. Further, I am interested in more than just peddlers and traders, e.g. knights errant, wandering monks would fit my definition.

Comment: Also, note that the Roma have been some countries (eg: Turkey) longer than the dominant ethnicity has been there. In many others, they aren't a whole lot newer.

Comment: @pollywog - Are you looking at this on a global scale? Without a specific time frame? Might be too broad if so. Can't the question be clearer, more focused? If nothing else, to at least restrict the answer to something useful perhaps?

Comment: @JAsia, I wish to prove/disprove my hypothesis that a certain country during a certain historical period had more indigenous "peripatetic minorities" than any other country in any other historical period. By historical period, I mean when records were kept, since there is no other way to prove their existence. I understand it is a difficult question to answer, but I don't see how I can be more specific while answering my question. The best contender so far is India, which apparently had [1.2% population of nomads] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomads_of_India).

Comment: @pollywog - Thank you for explaining further, but I still cannot get a _fix_ on this question, but others might. By the way, history is not reduced to records-keeping only viz " *...  since there is no other way to prove their existence*". I think you've just discounted the entire field of archaeology. That Wiki link merely refers to nomadic groups, in India in this case, and in the same category, at the bottom - [**Nomadic groups of Eurasia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Nomadic_groups_in_Eurasia). I suspect you might get an answer quicker if this question is framed differently.

Comment: @pollywog  So, are you asking for the largest known example of a peripatetic community in particular, or do you also want to include any form of nomadic group that might live "on the fringes" of permanent settlements?  (One key distinction would be self-sufficiency.)

Comment: @pollywog  "I wish to prove/disprove my hypothesis that a certain country during a certain historical period had more indigenous "peripatetic minorities" than any other country in any other historical period."  It might have been helpful to have simply asked this first place.  ;)  Why not edit your question with the specifics you're concerned with?